# Why did they feed snake blood to the girl baby?

Tags: plot-explanation, end-of-days

In **End of Days**, why did they feed snake blood to the girl baby?

[image]

Actually, it didn't help her, still she dreams about making love with Satan everyday.

What is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They feed her snake blood to make her the betrothed of Satan and the mother of the antiChrist.

From [Capalert](http://www.capalert.com/capreports/endofdays.htm)

> At the beginning of the movie a newborn girl was taken from her mother immediately after birth to a darkened room of the hospital. There, the baby was chanted over and fed snake blood (remember the snake in the Garden of Eden?) to make her the betrothed of Satan and the mother of the antiChrist. **I know of nowhere in the Bible that it tells us Satan will sire the antiChrist with a human woman** -- a mockery of the human yet immaculate birth of baby Jesus? The snake in the movie was a rattlesnake. Having witnessed a rattlesnake roundup in Sweetwater, Texas I can tell you rattlesnakes do not bleed like the one in this movie.